# Problema con manejo de arrays en C++

Tags: c++, array

Qué tal. Estoy empezando en c++ con un programa para exportar datos en formato de cita bibliográfica:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Spanish");
    char autor[40], anio_public[4], nombre_articulo[60], nombre_pagina[30], texto en negritafecha_consulta[30], url[100];
    stringstream cadena;
    cout<<"Autor:\n"<<endl;
    cin.getline(autor,40);
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Año de publicación:\n"<<endl;
    cin.getline(anio_public,4);
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Nombre del artículo:\n"<<endl;
    cin.getline(nombre_articulo,60);
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Nombre de página consultada:\n"<<endl;
    cin.getline(nombre_pagina,30);
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Fecha de consulta:\n"<<endl;
    cin.getline(fecha_consulta,30);
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Link:\n"<<endl;
    cin.getline(url,100);
    system("cls");
    cadena<<autor<<". ("<<anio_public<<"). "<<nombre_articulo<<". "<<nombre_pagina<<". [Internet], ("<<fecha_consulta<<"), [Disponible en]: "<<url<<endl;
    cout<<"\nBibliografía:\n\n"<<endl<<cadena.str();
    return 0;
}
```

El problema viene al pedir "Año de publicación", ya que tengo declarado un array `anio_public[4]` pero solo me permite ingresar 3 caracteres para seguir funcionando correctamente; al momento de ingresar los 4 caracteres necesarios, se ignoran todas las demás instrucciones de entrada de datos y me lleva al final del programa mostrando únicamente "Autor" y los primeros 3 caracteres ingresados de "Año de publicación".

Cadena con 3 caracteres ingresados:

```
autor= Autor 1  
anio_public= 123    //3 caracteres  
nombre_articulo= articulo 1  
nombre_pagina= pagina 1  
fecha_consulta= fecha/consulta 1  
url= url de consulta
```

> Autor 1. (123). articulo 1. pagina 1. [Internet], (fecha/consulta 1), [Disponible en]: url de consulta

Cadena con 4 caracteres ingresados:

```
autor= Autor 1  
anio_public= 1234    //4 caracteres
/*
nombre_articulo= articulo 1  
nombre_pagina= pagina 1  
fecha_consulta= fecha/consulta 1        *todo esto ya no lo toma en cuenta
url= url de consulta
*/
```

> Autor 1. (123). . . [Internet], (), [Disponible en]:

Ya intenté cambiando el tamaño el tamaño del array, cambiar el tipo de dato a string o int, reubicar la linea al final, pero me sigue dando problemas.
Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que las cadenas de texto, en C++, **siempre** requieren de un caracter que finaliza la cadena, que es `\0`.

Así, ante una secuencia como 2019, la cadena resultante contiene lo siguiente:

```
00 01 02 03 04
 2  0  1  9 \0
```

Así, si tu objetivo es guardar 4 caracteres tendrás que declarar un array con capacidad para 5 caracteres.

Si no cumples con este requisito, el buffer se desbordará y empezarás a sobreescribir memoria que no pertenece a ese array sino a variables vecinas.

Así, el array deberías declararlo así:

```
char anio_public[5];
```

Aunque ya puestos podías usar `std::string` en vez de arrays de caracteres y te quedaría todo más limpio:

```
std::string anio_public;
std::cin >> anio_public;
```

O, mejor aún, dado que en esa variable vas a guardar un número... por qué no declarar la variable de tipo entero?

```
int anio_public;
std::cin >> anio_public;
```